# Unity C# script throws "object you're trying to instantiate is null" error, but only when the script is on a prefab object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I have a script set up to be called by an animation event to instantiate an object. This works just fine when the script is placed on a GameObject that is **already** in the scene; however, it does not work when the script is placed on an object that has been instantiated into the scene.

ex: coffee brewer instantiates a coffee cup using the script (this works) --> that coffee cup then instantiates a cup sleeve (this throws error ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.). The script is as follows:

```
public GameObject product;//this part is always assigned in the inspector
private GameObject leftHand;
private GameObject barista;
private GameObject rightHand;


private void Start()
{
    leftHand = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("LeftHand");
    rightHand = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("RightHand");
    barista = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
}

public void instantiateItemInHand()
{
    
   
    if (!barista.GetComponent<BaristaController>().leftHandIsFull)//left hand isn't full
    {
        Instantiate(product, leftHand.transform) ;//put the object in the left hand
        
    }
    else if (!barista.GetComponent<BaristaController>().rightHandIsFull)//right hand isn't full
    {
        Instantiate(product, rightHand.transform);//put the object in the right hand
        
    }

}
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. The problem is most likely in the code that instantiates the cup sleeve. Is it the same MonoBehavior for both the Coffee Brewer and the Coffee Cup? If not, can you share it?
Can you also share screenshots of the prefabs of the Coffee brewer, Coffee cup, and Cup sleeve?

Comment: Please debug your code at runtime. `product` seems not to be referenced for all instances of your component .. do the objects get destroyed on runtime? Is the assigned reference in the scene or in the prefabs (`Assets`)?

Answer (score 0):

This actually had to do with the animation events. For some reason, the actual events had become null during the process of copying them over to one another.